# Browser with JavaScript TCP Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I have built a tcp server within node.js which receives and sends data to each client connecting to this server (clients in c++). Now I want the browser with javascript to connect to this server, but all I receive in the console of the server is this:

```
127.0.0.1:55680 message: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/
24.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 19YxKKtCqZeuxtOSlaoswg==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

my server in node looks like this (example from the internet):

```
// Load the TCP Library
net = require('net');

// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];

// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {

// Identify this client
socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort;

// Put this new client in the list
clients.push(socket);

// Send a nice welcome message and announce
socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");
broadcast(socket.name + " joined the server\n", socket);

// Handle incoming messages from clients.
socket.on('data', function (data) {
broadcast(socket.name + " message: " + data, socket);
});

// Remove the client from the list when it leaves
socket.on('end', function () {
clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
broadcast(socket.name + " left the server.\n");
});
// Send a message to all clients
function broadcast(message, sender) {
clients.forEach(function (client) {
// Don't want to send it to sender
if (client === sender) return;
client.write(message);
});
// Log it to the server output too
process.stdout.write(message)
}

}).listen(80);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
console.log("TCP Server running at localhost port 80\n");
```

my browser client in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    function connect()
    {
        // Websocket
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:80");

        // Nach dem öffnen des Sockets den Status anzeigen
        socket.onopen   = function()    { message('Socket Status: '+socket.readyState+' (open)');   }
        // Nach dem empfangen einer Nachricht soll diese angezeigt werden
        socket.onmessage= function(msg) { message('Empfangen: '+msg.data);                          }           

        // SENDEN
        function send()
        {
            var text = $('#text').val();    // Text aus textbox in Variable schreiben 
            socket.send(text);      // Den Text aus der Variable an den Socket senden
            message('Gesendet : '+text) // Anzeigen was gesendet wurde
            $('#text').val("");     // Text-Inhalt der Textbox löschen
        }

        // Funktion welche die Nchrichten an das Log anfügt
        function message(msg)
        {
            $('#Log').append(msg+'</br>');
        }

        // Enter taste auf der TextBox zum senden behandeln
        $('#text').keypress(function(event) 
        {
            if (event.keyCode == '13') 
            {
                send();
            }
        }); 
    }

    connect();

});
```

The first message I pasted is the message I get in the server when my browser connects to the tcp server. I don't know how I can send data or write messages to the server. In addition to that I don't know why there is displayed such a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using just pure TCP connection in NodeJS. If you want to communicate via WebSockets you have to use some WS module on the server side (NodeJS) as well. Have a look at https://github.com/einaros/ws

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but when I want to communicate from a c++ application with this websocket, I can't send any messages to that server, just pure connection. I thought that it is possible with TCP and in the c++ application it works. But now I can't connect to the tcp server from my browser. My aim is to built up a connection beetween c++ and browser. No Webtoolkit or something else.

Comment: Well you have to use everywhere WebSockets or another options is use WS for communication between a browser and the server and then just sockets to communicate with c++.

Comment: Is that possible? How can I do that with node? Can I just create two servers? one TCP and one Websockets? In the same node.js file?

Comment: WebSocket Server is built over a TCP connection ,so you are going to have two TCP just with different processing of received data. If you don't know how to do it please ask a new question.

Comment: What should I write in this question? Let me know so I will ask and post a link here.

Comment: As I wrote above you need to basically make a WebSocketServer and also TCP server for C++ clients ,but let me first ask one question. Why you can't use WebSockets in C++ as well? For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916217/standalone-c-or-c-websocket-server-library If you could do it then you don't have to create any other server

Comment: I personally don't want to create the WebSockets-Server in the c++ application. That would work, I know, but the libwebsockets library is too complex for me. I have more knowledge in javascript. I will link the new question here.

Comment: Up to you ,but to have just one WSS is a lot more simplier, effective and cleaner solution. Please accept this answer if it did helped you.

Comment: It helped me well. I will post the new question in about 40mins, because I'm not allowed to right now. Will link it here.

Comment: Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058490/node-js-websocket-server-and-tcp-server-connection