# Node.js websocket-server and tcp-server connection

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, sockets, tcp

Related to this question [Browser with JavaScript TCP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056135/browser-with-javascript-tcp-client) I asked whether I can connect from a browser to a tcp server. I found out that it won't work so I asked for another solution. '0101' provided me to built up two servers. One tcp server for a c++ application that connects to and one websockets server that receives data from the browser. I have originally built up each one of them, but I don't know how to connect them so I can receive data from the browser in the c++ application.

Here is the websockets-server:

```
var ClientListe = {};
// Anzahl der Verbundenen Clients
var ClientAnzahl=0;

// Websocket-Server
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({host: '127.0.0.1',port: 80});

wss.on('connection', function(ws) 
{
    // Client-Anzahl hochzählen
    ClientAnzahl++;
    // Client-Verbindung mit in die Client-Liste Aufnehmen
    ws['AUTH'] = ClientAnzahl;
    ClientListe[ws['AUTH']] = ws;
    // Ausgabe
    console.log('client '+ClientAnzahl+' verbunden...');

    ws.on('message', function(message) 
    {
        console.log('von Client empfangen: ' + message);

        for(client in ClientListe)
        {
            ClientListe[client].send('von Server empfangen: ' + message);
        }

    });

    ws.on('close', function() 
    {
        // Client aus der ClientListe Löschen
        delete ClientListe[ws['AUTH']];

        // Nachricht der Trennung an die Console ausgeben
        console.log('Client '+ ws['AUTH'] +' getrennt.');
    });

});
```

and here is the tcp server:

```
// Load the TCP Library
net = require('net');

// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];

// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {

// Identify this client
socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort;

// Put this new client in the list
clients.push(socket);

// Send a nice welcome message and announce
socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");
broadcast(socket.name + " joined the server\n", socket);

// Handle incoming messages from clients.
socket.on('data', function (data) {
broadcast(socket.name + " message: " + data, socket);
});

// Remove the client from the list when it leaves
socket.on('end', function () {
clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
broadcast(socket.name + " left the server.\n");
});
// Send a message to all clients
function broadcast(message, sender) {
clients.forEach(function (client) {
// Don't want to send it to sender
if (client === sender) return;
client.write(message);
});
// Log it to the server output too
process.stdout.write(message)
}

}).listen(80);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
console.log("TCP Server running at localhost port 80\n");
```

Both are copied out of the internet for testing some cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a TCP server (NodeJS example)

```
var net = require("net");

var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
    console.log('server connected');

    c.on('end', function() {
        console.log('server disconnected');
    });

    c.write('hello\r\n');
    c.pipe(c);
});

server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
    console.log('server bound');
});
```

Then in the same file (optionally of course) create a WS server with different port number

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    port: 8080
});

wss.on("connection", function(ws) {
    console.log("CONNECTED");

    // ws.on("message"), ws.on("close"), ws.on("error")
});
```

Now you should have two servers, one for regular sockets and another one for WebSockets.

// As I mentioned in the previous question and Pete as well, it is a lot better to use WebSockets in C++ as well instead of creating two servers...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can these two servers communicate? So for example the tcp server receives data and transports it to the websocketserver which sends it to the client?

Comment: Like the TCP Server first receives then sends as a client to the websocketserver.

Comment: All your clients are going to be in an array. If you will receive some data for instance using TCP connection you can send this data to WS client as `wsClients[clientID].send(someData);`

Comment: Ok, I don't understand it right now. Can you point it out as an example? I have the tcp server which receives an "hello world" from my c++ client with "send(sock, request.c_str(), request.length(), 0)". Then the server displays the message with:
socket.on('data', function (data) {
broadcast(socket.name + " message: " + data, socket);
});.... How can the tcp server transport this data to the websocket?

Comment: I think you should make some research and learn how WS/TCP server/communication works otherwise it is going to be hard. Before you send any data to WS clients you need to have some clients connected and saved in an array that I mentioned above. Check this out http://ahoj.io/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial I can't explain you completely everything what you need to do... I thought you know how to do it and you have got problem only run two servers.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it. What I didn't know was that I can forward message from the inside TCP server to the websocket server which are in the same file. In the websocket server I forwarded messages to clients like this: ClientListe[client].send('von Server empfangen: ' + message);. Same thing to tcp server? So I only take the ip and port from the tcp server and send the data to it?

Comment: Or do I first have to connect for example the tcp server to the ws server an the ws server says like "on.connect"

Comment: Sorry ,but I am lost. What IP and PORT? If you want to send data to a TCP client that is slightly different. Again you should have some array `tcpClients` ,but instead of `send` you have to use `write`. More http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback

Comment: Ok, for example the tcp server runs on port 80 and the websocket server runs on port 1337. I want to transfer data from the tcp server to the websocket server which is in the same file. How can I make an array of the TCP server to address him? Its just one tcp client I use (the server).

Answer (score 0):

Drop the TCP server and make the C++ client connect to the websockets server instead.  You'll need to implement the websockets protocol on top of your TCP connection at the C++ end (all you really need is a bit of pre-amble to negotiate the websocket).  You have problems here with both servers trying to use port 80.

By the way, you should also consider using HTTPS for the websocket instead of HTTP since it avoids problems with proxy traversal.  But get the HTTP case working first as this will be more complicated to implement on the C++ end.

Comment: So what I get from your comment is that I only have to use the websocket-server from node? I don't want to build a websocket-server in c++, but just connect to a server that receives data from the c++-application.

Comment: Make the C++ a websocket client.  You then only have 1 server you are talking to.
Another option would be to make the TCP server use a different port from the websocket server and additionally connect to the websocket server.  Otherwise how is the TCP server going to send stuff to the C++ client that was received by the websocket server?
Or, just make it possible for the websocket server to also accept TCP connections on a different port number (If it is possible in Node by creating multiple servers?).  Then pass messages to clients of the TCP server when the websocket server receives data.

Comment: i.e. the websocket server would need to have a variable that points to the tcp server in the latter case of my previous comment.

Comment: How can I make the c++ a websocket client? I have no idea about the libwebsockets library for c++ or something else. Is it possible to realize this easier?

Comment: Maybe look at this:

http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp

Or try implementing the websocket handshake yourself on your TCP socket.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/443660/Building-a-basic-HTML-client-server-application

Comment: Thank you very much Pete. We also discussed at my office to built a tcp server inside the c++ application and connect the websockets server to its ip. also a possbile solution?

Comment: @user3705887 unlikely if you want the server to be on a machine that is on the other side of a NAT router.  It would work on a simple LAN though.  This is why the websockets only approach is ideal - everything goes down port 80 (or 443 for secure websockets) and you don;t need to open up any ports on the server.